# Calculate date pattern and predict

Tags: algorithm, math, statistics, observer-pattern

I have a list of dates which indicates when the job finished running successfully: The list can be millions of dates

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS

2016-01-01 05:00:00

2016-01-02 05:00:00

2016-01-05 13:00:00

2016-01-06 13:00:00

2016-01-09 05:00:00

2016-01-10 05:00:00
```

Occasionally, the job might have failed and delay the process by few hour to few days:

```
2016-01-13 14:00:00

2016-01-15 14:00:00

2016-01-19 06:00:00

2016-01-20 06:00:00
```

The pattern obviously is 1 and 3 day for this list.

My question is, how can I figure out the pattern of any arbitrary list of dates, able to ignore the delay, and estimate the next date that the job will be finish running?

I need to estimate and produce a date that accurately-ish predicted when will the job finish next time, using the date that occur the most, and ignore delay if possible.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: So you mean that you need the "Smallest" timespan elapsed between runs?

Comment: Isn't this more of a math or statistics than a programming question?

Comment: I need the most accurate date of the job, not time span and not the smallest, using the date that occur the most and able to ignore the error if possible. And I need to figure a way to program it :(

Comment: In this case, the next estimated date will be 2016-01-23 13:00:00, the date list can be millions of lines

Comment: This sounds very similar to [Poisson Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).  You may be able to model this using the existing data and make a prediction.  Although, this distribution assumes that each event is random and isn't affected by the previous event.